# Sortorder in MVC ASP

Tags: sql-order-by

I have asp mvc and the output must be in order, first by Column and *then by* delivery point

```
var columnItems = stack.PriceLists
    .OrderBy(p => p.ColumnOrder)
    .OrderBy(p => p.DeliveryPoint.DeliveryPointId)
    .Skip(5*n).Take(5);
```

The output however orders by deliverypoint. Please help?!?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, it's easy! There is ThenBy, so I just replace the OrderBy and the ThenBy.